# View executed sql from dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms, dynamic-sql

I've inherited a complicated application that uses a lot of dynamic SQL. Many of the stored procedures construct and execute significantly different SQL statements depending on input parameters. Is there a way that I can see the executed SQL, without using SQL profiler - ideally from within SQL Server Manager Studio?

Comment: Add `PRINT @statement` in the end of procedure and manually execute that proc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PRINT statement

for exp.

```
IF @@OPTIONS & 512 <> 0
    PRINT N'This user has SET NOCOUNT turned ON.';
ELSE
    PRINT N'This user has SET NOCOUNT turned OFF.';
GO
```

use like

```
PRINT @YourDynamicSQLStatement
```

ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176047.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I did something more-or-less along the same lines by creating a table called 'WhatHappened' with an AutoInc BigInt as a primary key, and a big varchar(8000) field to hold the dynamically created SQL commands, and then simply wrote the dynamically created SQL into the table, and looked at it with Enterprise Manager later.  I don't know if it's a great solution, but it was quick and simple and worked.